# Modelling data for Analysis & reports

Tags: oracle, database-design, data-modeling, star-schema

I am trying to build a star schema for some engraving data. The egraving data i get along with my orders from my source is in the below format.

```
Ex 1. BK: S2: This ^ May, 2018 ^ is engraved ^ on my ring
Ex 2. LFT: S2: Love You  ^ SY#LValways SY#EWA
```

In the above 2 examples.

- BK(Back),LFT(left front) represents the location of engraving.
- S2: represents the font.
- ^ represents a new line
- SY#LV SY#EWA represents the symbol to be engraved

I would build a datamodel so i am able to answer the following business questions

```
1. Most used location.
2. count of symbols used in an order.
3. Most used font.
4. No of multiline orders.
```

Below is the design i am thinking to build.

1. Attribute Desc Table. This will have one attribute value for each attribute value like font ,symbol, text

   | Attribute | Attribute desc |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | font |
   | 2 | location |
   | 3 | symbol |
   | 4 | Text |
2. Attribute table. This will store a new row for each attribute of the engraving order.

For Ex

```
| Order number | Attribute  | Attribute value | line number|
| -------- | -------------- |
|1234      | 2              |BK               | 1          |
|1234      | 1              |S2               | 1          |     
|1234      | 4              | This            | 1          |
|1234      | 2              |BK               | 2          |
|1234      | 1              |S2               | 2          |     
|1234      | 4              | May, 2018       | 2          |
|1234      | 2              |BK               | 3          |
|1234      | 1              |S2               | 3          |     
|1234      | 4              | is engraved     | 3          |
|1234      | 2              |BK               | 4          |
|1234      | 1              |S2               | 4          |     
|1234      | 4              | on my ring      | 4          |
```

Is this the correct data model design. Is there a better data model design for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks OK. If, by any chance, a new attribute appears in the future, you'll easily add it into the `attribute_desc` table and use it in `attribute`.

Make sure to create primary key on `attribute_desc.attribute` column which will then be referenced by `attribute.attribute` column (I'm talking about a foreign key).